# Will it be possible to install an office add-in without the need to use the add-in store

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

I had created a sample office add-in as per the instructions given in quick start guide
and try to do sideloading as per the instructions given in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/dev/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac

Here to use my addins I need to do following
1. do npm start which start the dev server
2. paste the manifest file to location: /Users//Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Word/Data/Documents/wef

Can someone answer the following question
1. What happens when we installed an add-ins from office-store.?
2. Folder location where add-ins gets placed

Regards,
Alam

Answer (score 0):

We have 3 deployment solutions:

1. Sideload
2. AppStore
3. Centralized Deployement

It would be easy for an administrator to deploy Office Add-ins to users and groups within their organization. Add-ins deployed via the admin center are available to users in their Office applications right away, with no client configuration required. You can use Centralized Deployment to deploy internal add-ins as well as add-ins provided by ISVs.

Comment: That doesn't seem too useful when SharePoint is centrally controlled, but child companies want to develop / deploy / use their own add-ins independantly. Is there any way to create add-ins that are part of a document?

Comment: how would Centralized Deployment work on O365 On-Premise? 0365 Admin panel is not an option in that case